# python3 summurize from a list

Tags: python-3.x

```
def check_pnr (a):
    for i in range (len (a)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            res1 = a[i] * 2
            res2 = (res1 % 10) + (res1 // 10)
```

Guys I'm new with python, I've just started learning it, wish you could help with this.
How would you do to get the sum of the numbers I get from res2?

Comment: Just a tip, don't use `>` and backticks to format code. Just indent everything by four spaces by highlighting it and pressing ctrl+k.

Comment: And I think you'll need to elaborate on "How would you do to get the sum of the numbers I get from res2?". Are you intending to `return` from the function?

Comment: set `res2 = 0` before the loop then `res2 += ...`. Okay? (don't forget to `return res2`

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for the tip and for the editing :).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm doing as you suggested but I'm only getting the first element of the list when I do it :(.

Comment: of course, `return` _outside_ the loop (now you'll think I'm reading your mind)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre hahaha!! thank you very much for your help!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix:

- accumulate instead of assign (setting at 0 before the loop)
- return the value (outside the loop, beware of indentation as always)

code:

```
def check_pnr (a):
    res2 = 0
    for i in range (len (a)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            res1 = a[i] * 2
            res2 += (res1 % 10) + (res1 // 10)
    return res2
```

for the record & the beauty of the thing, I would write that in one line using nested generator comprehensions and `sum`:

```
def check_pnr(a):
    return sum((res1 % 10) + (res1 // 10) for res1 in (a[i]*2 for i in range(0,len(a),2)))
```

(note that using a step in `range` saves the even number testing)